# Selecting a single column in treeview tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How can I select a single column in treeview tkinter, when I try to use the `tree.get_children()` it only let me chose a item.

Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to be more specific. Did you set `selectmode` for your treeview widget? or do you want to highlight a column using `focus`?

Comment: I want to insert the second column data into a sqlite database, but i am not being able to select only the column that I want, there are 3 columns in the treeview table

Comment: A workaround will be finding the column by `event.x`, and then use `tree.getchildren()` to get all cells in that column. You won't be able to highlight an entire column though.

Comment: Thank you for the help Henry !

Answer (score 0):

The treeview widget doesn't support selecting data by column. You can only select by row.

Comment: Can I insert the entire table into a  sqlite db though ?

Comment: @PedroMiotti: yes, of course. the db doesn't care where the data comes from as long as it's in the correct format.

Comment: All right, I will find a way to do it, thanks for the help Bryan !

Comment: For any chance do you know how to insert in the correct format, because i tried once before and i got this error :                               
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @PedroMiotti: inserting data into databases is fairly well documented, and there are probably hundreds if not thousands of questions on this site. It depends on what your database is, what tables and columns it has, where you're getting the data, etc.